# Do static waits or something like browser.pause(#seconds) (in javascript) work in a headless mode?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I am building tests on Vscode using javascript and having some static waits using browser.pause(#secs). When I run it locally on my machine, it works fine, but when it runs on Jenkins in a headless mode, I get this error:

```
 Error:  Unable to load spec files quite likely because they rely on `browser` object that is not fully initialised.
`browser` object has only `capabilities` and some flags like `isMobile`.
Helper files that use other `browser` commands have to be moved to `before` hook.
Spec file(s): /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Testing/Automated-FrontEnd-Integration-Tests/Automation_Tests/EndlessWebdriverAutomationSuite/test/specs/eventsTests.js
Error: Error: Cannot find module '../commonSteps/eventsSteps'
Require stack:
- /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Testing/Automated-FrontEnd-Integration-Tests/Automation_Tests/EndlessWebdriverAutomationSuite/test/specs/eventsTests.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1039:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:885:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Testing/Automated-FrontEnd-Integration-Tests/Automation_Tests/EndlessWebdriverAutomationSuite/test/specs/eventsTests.js:6:20)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1218:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1272:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1081:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:12)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:167:29)
```

What is the problem, and how can it be fixed?

I tried to run it locally on my machine in a headless mode, this error does not show but other issues show.

Comment: Can you add code with your test?

Comment: its split on multiple classes but here it is in the specs class:
 it('Join an event', async () => {
    await browser.url('/login')
    await loginSteps.login('rodaina.gamal@rubikal.com', 'qwerty@1')
    await browser.pause(1000)
    const joinEventFlag = await eventsSteps.joinAnEvent()
    await expectChai(joinEventFlag).to.be.true
  })